# Roundel vs Roundabout

Tags: differences, british-english

What, if any, is the difference between the two?

My best guess is that a 'roundel' is the traffic island or structure that you drive around, while the 'roundabout' also includes the road you're driving on.

Comment: This seems like a general reference. If you look up both words in the Oxford English Dictionary, _roundel_ is defined as "Something circular, spherical, curved, or cylindrical" (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167955?redirectedFrom=roundel#eid), while _roundabout_ is defined as "a junction of several roads consisting of a central (usually circular) island around which traffic moves in one direction" (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167944?rskey=7egTOH&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid, definition 8). You might want to visit the Help Center, which outlines how you can ask good, on-topic questions.

Comment: @Nicole While OED is not available to all, the dictionaries at The Free Dictionary echo what you quote. RHK Webster's includes the extremely wide 'something round'. While this covers unusual usages, it doesn't give much help on what it would sound outlandish to include.

Comment: Based on the two answers given thus far and my own gut instinct, this seems to be a BrE word that is not used in the US. I have added the [tag:british-english] tag to reflect this.

Comment: That seems like a good call. _Roundabout_ is commonly used  in the U.S., but _roundel_ is not.

Comment: "Roundel" will get you a dumb look in the US.  The US term is "roundabout" or, probably more often, "traffic circle".

Comment: @HotLicks Technically, a [roundabout is different from a traffic circle](https://www.dot.ny.gov/main/roundabouts/background), and the term *rotary* is used by some in New Jersey and in New England for the latter.

Comment: @choster - Yeah, I do recall "rotary" from my New Jersey days, but that was 40 years ago, and half the "rotaries" had the center island cut through and traffic lights installed.  And the purported distinction between roundabout and traffic circle is only there if people know what it is, which they don't.

Answer (score 11):

In Britain, a roundel **in this context** is the white circle in the middle of a *mini-roundabout.* This one is fairly large, since it's bus-size:

[image: Roundel in mini-roundabout]
<sup>[from [Surface Markings Ltd](http://www.surface-markings.co.uk/services/road-markings.html)]</sup>

Traffic is to circulate around the white blob as though it were a full-size roundabout [see below], and only go over it if that is unavoidable — as it would be for the bus turning right. Roundels can often be slightly humped, or simply painted on the road as here.

From a report on [Lexology.com](http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=b0ac006c-b7f5-4c08-b286-2d8faed71922) (my emphases):

> Mr Starks reached the roundabout first, entered it and began his right turn, taking a line which involved passing over the top part of the **roundel.** PC Richardson entered the roundabout very shortly after him. She did not moderate her speed or her course in any way and was taking a line that involved passing directly over the middle of the **roundel.** She struck Mr Starks’ car in the centre of the junction.

A roundabout is rather larger, and the centre is not designed to be driven over:

[image: Cloghogue Roundabout, Northern Ireland]
<sup>[from [Aubrey Dale](http://www.geograph.org.uk/profile/5835) via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_roads_in_Ireland#Roads_in_Northern_Ireland)]</sup>

---

Just for completeness, *roundel* is also used to refer to the Underground sign adopted by Transport for London

[image: London Underground roundel] <sup>[London Underground via [TFL](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/corporate/about-tfl/culture-and-heritage/art-and-design/the-roundel)]</sup>

and particularly to RAF plane markings (and derivatives in Commonwealth realms' air forces such as the [RCAF](http://www.rcaf-arc.forces.gc.ca/en/index.page), [RAAF](http://www.airforce.gov.au/About-us/About-the-RAAF/Air-Force-Roundel/?RAAF-19j/ms/wfJI7szJiav0qS4757UzFI9b7) and [RNZAF](http://www.airforce.mil.nz/default.htm))

[image: RAF roundel] <sup>[[helluvit Sports Car Club](http://www.helluvit.co.uk/index.php?s=down&&maincategory_id=17&&subcategory_id=34)]</sup>

Comment: The only way I can think of improving this answer is to take the photos on a sunny day.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You'll have to find a roundabout in another country then; we've had our half hour of sun this year!

Comment: The French air-force also has roundels, with red on the outside and blue in the middle.

Comment: @WS Almost all air forces have roundels: a famous one is the US Air Force, with the star in the middle. A roundel is any circular design.

Answer (score 4):

A "roundel" is any circular design, for example used by many companies and air forces to identify themselves. Wikipedia has a number of examples of [military](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_aircraft_insignia#Current_insignia_of_national_air_forces) and [non-military](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundel#Other_roundels) usage.

In this context, the roundel refers to the painted circle in the middle of a small roundabout (such a roundabout is usually referred to as a "mini-roundabout"). However, I've never heard it referred to as such: unless you need to specifically talk about the painted road markings, rather than the road layout itself, you'd talk about the roundabout, rather than the roundel.

Answer (score 0):

My (American) dictionary has *roundel* only for a small medallion or badge, or a short poem.

Comment: Yeah, in the US, the roadway is a "traffic circle" and anything in the middle of it is an "island". (Unless there's a statue there, or some example of ancient architecture - in which case we'd say something like, "Go around the "monument", and take the second left.")

Comment: @Oldbag Even in the UK, the road junction is just called a roundabout. "Roundel" refers specifically to the painted centre marking of a very small roundabout.

Comment: In the US, the roadway is either a "traffic circle" or a "roundabout," depending on the region (much like "soda" vs. "pop").

Comment: @Nicole Technically, a [roundabout is different from a traffic circle](https://www.dot.ny.gov/main/roundabouts/background), and the term *rotary* is used by some in New Jersey and in New England for the latter.